# Python 3 smtp error

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send an email using smtplib for python 3, but i get this error message when sending.

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 854, in sendmail
msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: It might be helpful to include the code you are using that generates this error.

Comment: Also show us the first couple of lines of `msg`. Since it is the 4th character of the message, I suspect you are trying to put non-ascii characters into an email header, at a guess, `To:`. That isn't allowed. If you want to do that you have to encode them into ascii.